# When is mContext null-cleared? (widget, adapter etc.)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, frameworks, android-context

I'm fighting with memory leaks now.

Just out of curiosity,
when is mContext, the member of View or Adapter classes, null-cleared?

I couldn't find a part doing such a thing...

**EDIT:**

**I know about GC, but for example,**

**an ArrayAdapter has mContext, and if Activity has the reference to the ArrayAdapter,
is this a circular reference?**

Comment: Did you heard about garbage collector?

Comment: Whenever is possible try to pass the application context (`getContext().getApplicationContext()`).Its the most permanent context you have. Passing the activity around to other classes will very likely leave a lot of hanging reference to activities. Once I had 42 instances of the same Activity class in the heap when I should have only one, due a circular reference caused by an inner class that was also passed around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be cleared until garbage collector will get it. In other words - you shouldn't worry about clearing your variables, since they all will be collected by GC if there is no references to them (not instantly, but they will).

But there is one class in Android that causes troubles - `Bitmap`. If there is memory leaks in your app, first of all - look at bitmap usage. Make sure that you called `recycle` when you finished with it.

Answer (score 2):

Checking when null variables will get freed is beyond your control. But you can avoid the OOME problems.

As Dmitry said, if you are using `Bitmaps`, immediately call its `recycle()` method after use.
This way you can clear the resources you have held and make space for the application to run.

Calling GC is of no use since, even if you call it, it is not sure whether GC will free up your resources.

Also check if you have no memory leak problem in your code. Since this can also lead to OOME. You can check the memory leak problem by using [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php)(plugin) for eclipse.

Even if this does not solve your problem, ask us, we'll try to find another solution.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The context is generally the owning activity, which is managed by Android. It is guaranteed to be active and valid, until the Activity is active. Unless you are doing something tricky or fairly low level, you shouldn't be concerted about `mContext` in views and adapters.

What you should be concerned about is storing a reference to an activity (such as in a `Context mContext` or similar field) in a class that can potentially live longer than the activity (service, thread, application class, etc.). This will prevent the system from properly GC-ing the activity and will lead to memory leaks and subtle bugs.